# RabbitMqHostConfigurator UseCluster method not working

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a RMQ Cluster setup on Amazon EC2. Now when I try to create a RabbitMQ host by setting the cluster members, I get the **Broker Unreachable** exception every time. However, if I comment that UseCluster method, things start working fine. But I am not able to enjoy full benefits of cluster in that case.
Following is the piece of code I am working with:

```
foreach(var server in servers)
{
  try
  {
    var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
      var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(server), hst =>
      {
        hst.Username(settings.UserName);
        hst.Password(settings.Password);
        hst.UseCluster(c =>
        {
          c.ClusterMembers = servers;
        });
      });
      //Check if the connection is reachable
      host.Settings.GetConnectionFactory().CreateConnection();
      registrationAction?.Invoke(cfg, host);
    });
    AddBusToContainer(container, bus);
    return bus;
  }
  catch (BrokerUnreachableException ex)
  {
    EventLog.WriteEntry($"Error trying to connect to {server}", $"{ex}", EventLogEntryType.Error);
    continue;
  }
}
```

In the above code, if I comment the UseCluster implementation, I am able to successfully test the connection. But I receive the BrokerUnreachableException with the above code.

Does anyone have any idea about how to configure RMQ Cluster when creating a MassTransit bus? It would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure a cluster, you should only configure a single bus instance (you're configuring multiple in your example). I don't know what version of MassTransit you're using (it looks older, given the syntax), but this represents the current approach if you're hand-coding the bus.

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Host("cluster", hst =>
    {
        hst.Username(settings.UserName);
        hst.Password(settings.Password);
        
        hst.UseCluster(c =>
        {
            foreach(var server in servers)
                c.Node(server);
        });
    });

    registrationAction?.Invoke(cfg);
});

AddBusToContainer(container, bus);

return bus;
```

Though I would suggest using the newer syntax with your container, to ensure components are properly registered.

```
container.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Host("cluster", hst =>
        {
            hst.Username(settings.UserName);
            hst.Password(settings.Password);

            hst.UseCluster(c =>
            {
                foreach(var server in servers)
                    c.Node(server);
            });
        });

        registrationAction?.Invoke(cfg);
    });
})
```

Comment: 1. I am not creating multiple bus instances. The first bus that has proper host connection is added to the container and returned from the method.
2. Will there be any difference in setting ClusterMembers property instead of using the Node method.
3. My 'server' variable has the following format: "rabbitmq://{IP}/{VirtualHost}/"

Comment: Your server variable should just be `host[:port]` - there should not be any virtual host specified as it must be the same for each node. The port is optional, and will use the default if not specified.

Comment: I have four IPs in my 'servers' variable which are all RMQ instances. If the 1st and 4th RMQ instance are not running, I get an exception "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond {First RMQ IP}:5672". Is this by design or can we make it to try connection with every IP of cluster

Comment: The nodes are passed to RabbitMQ, I'm not sure how it selects amongst them. FWIW, I would never use this, I put haproxy in front of the cluster like this: https://github.com/phatboyg/rabbitmq-cluster

Comment: @ChrisPatterson so is it either / or? I mean are we supposed to either use UseCluster method and pass all nodes to it or alternatively we can skip on that and just provide the haproxy host? Or we can do both? What is your recommendation? Thanks

Comment: If you setup haproxy, only specify the haproxy address, don't use the cluster stuff in MassTransit.